# What is permuted block-diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

I have been searching about permuted block-diagram matrixes, since far there is [Block matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix). But it seems i cannot find any **permuted block-diagonal matrix** explanation/example...

Can anybody explain with an example what is **permuted block-diagonal matrix** as simple as possible!??